# How to show full OPTION name in OpenCart 2 checkout and email notification?

Tags: php, email, opencart, opencart2.x

### I want to have my option names fully visible on all pages and email notifications.

By modifying `catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php` I have managed to fix the problem for shopping cart only, but option name is still being cut off on checkout totals and emails that buyer and admins receive.

---

### Here is example of my problem :

[image: problem picture, option names are cut off]

### Here is example of what I want to achieve on emails and checkout page:

[image: fixed problem for cart view only]

---

I have managed to remove that limitation **on shopping cart view only** by modifying `catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php` controller by replacing lines `112 - 115` with the following:

```
$option_data[] = array(
'name'  => $option['name'],
'value' => $value
);
```

Comment: you have to do same in checkout.php, and for email in controller/email/order.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do same changes for the checkout total and for Email

For checkout Total go to

controller/checkout/confirm.php on line 347

change

```
'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value)
```

to

```
'value' => $value
```

and for Email got to
model/checkout/order.php and on line 562

change

```
'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value)
```

to

```
'value' => $value
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I can never find my way in OCs MVC. Who in their right mind would deal with string representation in the `controller` anyway! }(

Comment: You are welcome, you can also do the same in controller/account/order.php if you need to do same thing when a user see its previous orders in his account dashboard.